# SharePoint Plan P and external user access

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-online, office-365

I Have a problem with External User Access. On of my clients (his administrator) has delete the SharePoint group name TeamSite site visitors. After that I cant add a External User. I have receive this information:

> There is no required to manage groups of users on this site. You can
>   create one yourself by following these instructions or manage
>   permissions on the site with advanced permissions.

I try to create new group with the same name - but without any results. Is there any function that will reset my all site to default? Can I create this group manually?

Waiting for replay.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allen Qiu MSFT Support has replay for my question:

> To resolve this issue, add the missing group or groups to the site. To
>   do this, follow these steps:
>
> 1.Browse to https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/_layouts/permsetup.aspx.
>   2.Within the appropriate section (Visitors, Members, or both), make sure that the Create a new group option button is selected.
>   3.Click OK at the bottom of the page.
>
> For your reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2632494